# On voice over(accessibility on IOS) reselecting of location on map is not happening, the pointer is just moving up

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, leaflet, accessibility, voiceover

On accessibility of iOS reselecting of location on map is not possible and when click on any location the marker just moving up
Our project using Ionic 6, angular 8, node 14

On accessibility of iOS reselecting of location on map is not possible and when click on any location the marker just moving up, need the selecting of particular location which is selected